# Snort content syntax

Tags: ids, snort

Is it possible to use the symbols <, /, >, space, in the content option of a Snort rule? Or should I use URL encoding instead?
Which syntax is correct?

1. `content:"%3Cscript%20"`
2. `content:"<script src"`
3. `content:"</script>"`

Comment: The content should contain what you want to match. Characters special to snort must be escaped as documented - see https://docs.snort.org/rules/options/payload/content: *Note: Certain characters must be either escaped (with '\' characters) or encoded in hex. These are: ';', '\', and '"'.*

Comment: Welcome to the community. As noted by Steffen, yes you need to hex encode these characters